# Yii2 url manager

Tags: php, yii

Как мне преобразовать `site.com/index.php?r=site/index` в `site.com/site/index`?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
return [
    'class'=>'yii\web\UrlManager',
    'enablePrettyUrl'=>true,
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'rules'=> []
];
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните его детали, чтобы другим было проще разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

На [этой](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html) странице описано свойство `'enablePrettyUrl' => true,`, я думаю это то, что Вам нужно.